# exec() not working properly within function in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, exec, spyder

I'm trying to use a function to create instances of a class. I'm doing it this way because I'm creating a database and I want to have a record of all the object names.

I'm trying to use exec() to create these class instances, but it doesn't seem to be working within Spyder, whilst it does work within the standard python conole. For example:

```
def function(command):
    exec(command, globals())
```

In the standard console:

```
>>> function("x = 1")
>>> x
1
```

Whereas in Spyder I get:

```
>>> function("x = 1")
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-266-6fcf9dfbd479>", line 1, in <module>
    x

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I've messed around with a few different 'global' setting etc but to no avail. Would appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

EXTRA INFO:
When I run a script that contains a function call in Spyder, exec seems to work. So if I run the following script:

```
def function(command):
    exec(command, globals())
function("y = 8")
```

then enter the following:

```
>>> y
8
```

However if i try and call the function in the interactive window:

```
>>> function("y = 6")
>>> y
8
```

Comment: "I'm trying to use exec() to create these class instances" you probably shouldn't be doing that to begin with

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how come?